# using web2py beautify to display a table

Tags: web2py

The BEAUTIFY helper displays nicely the result of a DAL select statement as a table.
I would like to use this feature to display a panda dataframe
I have tried several ways of formatting the input to BEAUTIFY but none of them does the job.
Any clue ?

Here is the snippet of controller code that returns a list of dict(key=column name) to the view

```
d = [{'Cone': 1, 'Ctwo': 2,'Cthree':3}, {'Cone': 5, 'Ctwo': 10, 'Cthree': 20},  
 {'Cone': 100, 'Ctwo': 200, 'Cthree': 300},
 {'Cone': 1000, 'Ctwo': 2000, 'Cthree': 3000}]
return dict (rows=d)
```

The view is like :

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

The resulting page is not formatted as a table : 
rows : 
Cone : 
1 
Cthree : 
3 
Ctwo : 
2

Thank you for your attention

Comment: A DAL select returns a `Rows` object, which has a method that converts it to a `SQLTABLE`, so the `BEAUTIFY` helper ultimately just passes off the `Rows` object to `SQLTABLE` to produce the table display. The list of dictionaries above has no such special method, so `BEAUTIFY` handles it in a more generic way -- it does not recognize that each dictionary has the same structure and could be represented as a table. You will not be able to use `BEAUTIFY` for this purpose and will instead need to construct a custom display.

Comment: Thanks you very much Anthony, its very clear